# How to join two strings in one line discord bot

Tags: string, discord, arguments, bots, capitalize

I need to join and capitalize arguments at the same time. Here's what I have:

```
@bot.command(brief="Za map napiš Rod a druh a vyskočí ti mapa výskytu!")
async def map(ctx, *args):
  if not args:
    await ctx.channel.send("Nenapsal jsi Rod a druh! \nVysvětlivka:")
    await ctx.channel.send("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/661985293834125342/808308254081417227/acz_map_command.png")
  
  else :
    await ctx.channel.send('Mapa výskytu: *{}*'.format(' '.join(args)))
    await ctx.channel.send('https://antmap.coc.tools/images/{}.png '.format('.'.join(args)))
```

and I need the arguments (it is always 1 - 3 args) to be capitalized before they are joined in the antmap... link
I want this: `!acz map cAmponotus herculeanus` (when I misspell, the bot automatically corrects it into: Camponotus herculeanus) in Discord to work just like `!acz map Camponotus herculeanus` (which works fine and the bot responds in the channel with: Mapa výskytu: arguments.
I have no idea how to make it work and if it is even possible, but it would be awesome! thx

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you have to have it capitalized? Why not use `lower()` or `upper()` instead?

Comment: yes, because the link won't work - if you do !acz map Lasius niger - the bot sends a link with the args you sent https://antmap.coc.tools/images/Lasius.niger.png and Lasius niger must be with L and the rest lowercase, because it's using the pictures named that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> args = ["tHis", "Is", "sOme", "senTence"]
>>> " ".join([arg.capitalize() for arg in args])
'This Is Some Sentence'
```

My `args` is just some example. Your args is already an list of strings.

If you just want to capitalize the first word:

```
" ".join(args).capitalize()
```